# Test Angular's $valid and $pristine states with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, validation, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a Jasmine test that is not liking the use of `$pristine` and `$valid` within my controller and outputs the following error:

> TypeError: 'scope[...].$pristine' is null or not an object

The test initiating this error is below:

```
it('should validate values correctly', function () {
    var scp = ngElement.scope();

    var tests = [
        {
            valid: true,
            validationOptions: {
                required: true
            },
            value: '1'
        }
    ];

    $.each(tests, function (testIndex, testItem) {
        scp.name = 'test';
        scp.value = testItem.value;
        $.each(testItem.validationOptions, function (itemKey, itemValue) {
            scp[itemKey] = itemValue;
        });
        scp.change();
        expect(scp.valid).toBe(testItem.valid);
    });
});
```

The function in the controller with the $pristine and $valid states is below:

```
    // Field change behaviours
    scope.change = function () {
        validate();
        ...
    };

    // Field level validation function
    function validate () {
        // If the field does not have a value and is pristine, scope.valid is undefined.
        // Otherwise the field is validated
        if ((!scope.value || scope.value.length === 0) && scope[scope.name].$pristine) scope.valid = undefined;
        else scope.valid = scope[scope.name].$valid;

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define form on the view, the formcontroller is injected into your controller with the name as specified on the form's name attribute.

Since your unit test does not create the actual view, your only option is to create a dummy formcontroller and the properties that you access on the scope manually. Something like

```
scp.formName={};  // formName should be the same that you refer with `scope.name`
scp.formName.$pristine=true;  // set value according to the test
scp.formName.$valid=true;   // set value according to the test.
```

Remember you dont want to test whether form directive works fine. It has already been tested with the framework,

Comment: Thanks and yep, I agree with your feedback. Only trying to get closer to 100% code coverage with Istanbul.